# Getting the public access URL for a FogBugz case that was emailed in

Tags: fogbugz

We have [FogBUGZ](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/) installed on FogBugz On Demand. I occasionally need to send an email containing a list of cases that were submitted via email to the person who originally submitted them. For this I would like to supply the original public access url that they would have received in the original cnofirmation email.

However I cannot seem to find that URL anywhere in the web interface. Is there an easy way to find these urls?

Comment: Has anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

we are doing a similar thing but with local Fogbugz.
This is what we do:
1. Call fogbugz API to get a list of cases
2. Store case numbers in a variable
3. Construct url links like this http://yourUrl/default.asp?insertCaseNumberHere

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/666225/3901618 you can get the public tickets for the selected cases (in this example filtered by a correspondent) using the following api call:

```
https://test.fogbugz.com/api.asp?cmd=search&q=correspondent:xyz@xyz.com&cols=ixBug,correspondent,sTicket,sTitle,dtOpened&token=123456789
```

where `sTicket` is

> the ticket for a case, which can be turned into a public ticket URL

Source: http://help.fogcreek.com/8202/xml-api

The response looks like this:

```
<case operations="edit,reopen,reply,forward,remind" ixBug="455">
  <ixBug>5455</ixBug>
  <sTicket>
    <![CDATA[5455_fq856r9ks6qr2rv9]]>
  </sTicket>
  <sTitle>
    <![CDATA[Title]]>
  </sTitle>
  <dtOpened>2013-03-06T14:33:32Z</dtOpened>
</case>
```

and then you can build the following URL:

```
https://test.fogbugz.com/default.asp?5455_fq856r9ks6qr2rv9
```